# stm32f469 FreeRTOS+STemWin with CubeMX and keil: Bad operand types (UnDefOT, Constant) for operator (*

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm making project generated with STM32CubeMX for stm32f469i-disco.

I have based setup on "FreeRTOSconfig.h" from "Demonstration" project in *STM32CubeFWF4V1.16.0* repo. Fresh project from CubeMX compiles without problems, but after adding STemWin lib "STemWin532_CM4_OS_Keil_ot.lib" I get the error

> "*..........\Middlewares\ThirdParty\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\RVDS\ARMCM4F\port.c(507):
>   error: A1586E: Bad operand types (UnDefOT, Constant) for operator (*"

Interesting fact is that "Demonstration" compiles without this error.

How do I get the project configured:

In CubeMX:

1. Add periphs needed: DMA2D, DSIHost, FMC etc.
2. Add BSP drivers for touchscreen etc.
   Now, it copiles without problems.
3. Clone "Clock Configuration" based on "Demonstations"
4. In "Configuration" tab I clone all configuration based on code from "Demonstrations"

Then in Keil:
 5. I update Include Path in target options.

6. Add all STemWin files and when i try to compile:
   *"...Bad operand types..."*

When I disable freertos in CubeMX and add non-OS STemWin lib it compiles without problems.
When I try to compile non_OS STemWin lib with FreeRTOS enabled, it fails with the same message.

*What have I tried to do?*
Update port.c. Nothing changed.

Am I missing something while creating project?

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 days to find out what might be the reason for this error, I just found it and my project now compiles with FreeRTOS enabled and all the other sources used initially. Well, it's apparently a recursive include for stm32f4xx_hal.h file. I have added some modules from the demo package and those have some dependencies. Because I wanted to strip out some functions from some modules, I have manually added the includes/resources for the functions needed, which has contributed to that error, as I did not add any guards to my includes.

The offending line was in port.c file, and the error was because of a wrong constant value passed to the assembly line 483: `mov r0, #configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY`

Replacing **configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY** with any numeric value has helped in compiling the code, but I thought I should not leave it like that and it would be much better if I found out the reason for the problem.

More could be found here: 
https://community.st.com/thread/44751-portc483-error-a1586e-bad-operand-types-undefot-constant-for-operator

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem while building a Nucleo-F401RE board firmware with CubeMX 4.25.
This problem started just after setting LL driver use (Low-Level driver) instead of HAL in a CubeMX setting dialog.
I think this problem is from complicit in C definition of header file.
Including LL driver header may change `__NVIC_PRIO_BITS` definition in somewhere.

```
#ifdef __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
#define configPRIO_BITS         __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
#else
#define configPRIO_BITS         4
#endif
#define configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY (configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS))
```

Changing `__NVIC_PRIO_BITS` to `4` in a generated source code will solve the problem.

```c
/* mov r0, #configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY */
mov r0, #(configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - 4))
```